# Why it is called "Linear" Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'+P(x) \cdot y=Q(x)$$

Why it's called **Linear** Differential Equation? The function y might be curved.

Comment: It's the differential equation which is linear, not the solution.  (But I don't know why such things are called linear.  I have guesses, but just that.)

Comment: Because differential operator : $\hat{L}=\frac{d}{dx}+P(x)$  is a linear operator.

Comment: @FatihAydin no, just let this question be closed. You can keep this question undeleted.